# Yii and .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, yii

I want to redirect pages from **my_site.com/gamenews.php?id={ID}** to **my_site.com/news/{ID}/**, but can't :(

**My .htaccess file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php /$1/index [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^gamenews\.php\?id=(.*) /news/$1/ [L,R]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**Error that displays:**

Unable to process request "gamenews.php"

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is your question correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/ gamenews.php?id=$1[L,R]
```

1. The rewrited url should go first
2. [0-9] means that second parameter should be a number

Comment: Euh.. What do you want to achieve with `RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php /$1/index [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: Ignore my answer. I misunderstood the question. Here is a link that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377530/htaccess-redirect-301-url-rewrite

Comment: I want get redirect for search engines.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your htaccess rules might be your problem in addition to your syntax. Unless I misunderstood your question.

Try this in your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) gamenews.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php /$1/index [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: Unable to process request "gamenews.php"